# does OData supports groupby for Enum type?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

**Version of OData:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="5.9.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="6.15.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="6.15.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="6.15.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

**Enum for color:**

```
public enum Color
{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 3
}
```

**Vehicle class:**

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Guid VehicleId { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Color? Color { get; set; }
}
```

**Web API endpoint:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("vehicles")]
public IHttpActionResult GetVehicles(ODataQueryOptions<Vehicle> options)
{
    var query = dbContext.Vehicle.Select(x => new Vehicle
        {
            VehicleId = x.VehicleId,    // guid type for x.VehicleId
            Color = (Color?)x.ColorId    // nullable int type for x.ColorId
        });

    var odataQuery = options.ApplyTo(query) as IQueryable<object>;

    return Ok(odataQuery.AsEnumerable<Vehicle>());
}
```

**Scenario 1:**

Try http://localhost:1000/vehicles?$apply=groupby((vehicleId)) and it's working.

**Scenario 2:**

But with http://localhost:1000/vehicles?$apply=groupby((color)), this will throw error message ("exceptionMessage": "Argument types do not match").

Comment: I have the same issue, using ODATA-v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer from the odata.org [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/odata-discussion/HzFlP8GfgXs).

> From a specification perspective enum types are primitive types, so
>   they can be used in groupby.
>
> This does however not guarantee that your preferred tool set already
>   supports this.